# AS3: Designing a custom collection class

Tags: actionscript-3

**Task:**

Design a class that is a collection of other objects and could be used in *for each (..)*

```
public class Cards
{
    public function add( $Card : Card ) { ... }
}

//...

var $Cards:Cards = new Cards();
//...
for each ( var $Card:Card in $Cards) {
    // do things
}
```

My **first attemt** was to use *Array* class as parent:

```
public class Cards extends Array { ... }
```

This works great but *Cards* class inherits lots of *Array*'s public methods that shouldn't be visible in *Cards* objects like *sort()*, *push()*, *forEach()*, etc

**Second attempt** was to define base class as *dynamic*:

```
public dynamic class Cards { ... }
```

This works, but in this case I should define *every* child class as dynamic too:

```
public dynamic class Cards { ... }
...
var $Cards:Cards = new Cards();
$Cards.add( new Card() ); // works well
```

but

```
public class Player_Cards extends Cards { ... }
...
var $PlayerCards:Cards = new Player_Cards();
$PlayerCards.add( new Card() ); // error, Player_Class should be defined as dynamic too
```

Interesting thing is that if I use *Array* class as parent I shouldn't define child classes as *dynamic*

So, **the question is**:
Is it possible to design a collection class in AS3 that could be used in *for each (...)* and will not contain any unnessary methods (like from *Array* class)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this extending the [Proxy](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/flash/utils/Proxy.html) class.

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080145/extending-as3s-array-access-operators-to-wrap-out-of-bound-index-values) for some pointers on how to do this.

Comment: @thenduks. I though the same when I first learned about proxy's existence. (Though I never really used it in a real project, just played around a bit with it).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to subclass `Object` and implement [`propertyIsEnumerable`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Object.html#propertyIsEnumerable()).